# ¿Cómo funciona el reporte de cierre preguntas?

Tags: soporte, reportes

Recientemente se publico la siguiente pregunta:

[Cuales herramientas ORM son las mejores para PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/103001/cuales-herramientas-orm-son-las-mejores-para-php)

Que se basa en opiniones, pero al parecer reportarla como cierre convierte el reporte en votación para cerrar la pregunta, **¿esto es normal o podría ser un bug?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En [esta pregunta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269745/3045491) de meta SO dice:

> With over 3,000 rep you can't flag as a duplicate any more. You can only vote to close.

Traducción:

> Con más de 3k de reputación no puedes reportar como duplicado (u otro cierre). Sólo puedes votar para cerrar.

Sin embargo en los comentarios a esa respuesta dicen que **sigue saliendo la opción de reportar**. A lo que contesta el moderador que ese reporte se convertirá en un voto de cierre.

Por lo que cuando tienes la reputación para votar el cierre, un reporte automáticamente deja ese voto.

Comment: Sí, yendo desde "cerrar" y desde "reportar" se llega al mismo sitio: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdMUU.png y https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fwFC.png

Comment: @lois6b También me di cuenta de que reportar de esta manera no cuenta para la medalla de 500 reportes por eso surge mi duda, ya no se toma como reporte sino como voto de cierre

Comment: @JuanPinzón exacto. En ese caso los reportes de esa medalla que se tienen en cuenta, creo, son contenido no deseado, irrespetuoso o abusivo, muy baja calidad, se necesita la intervención de un moderador, no es una respuesta y los comentarios que no son ya necesarios. Mira [esta respuesta de meta SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253620/3045491) hehe

Comment: @lois6b me quedó claro, gracias por la información :-)